# my subdiv modifier pulls the model out of shape

Tags: modeling

I was following this tutorial [Blender Character Modeling 2 of 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VswCmVMLiEE)

and when I switch the subdiv modifier on and I move points about it just pulls the model out of shape, makes the surface react like weird scales and makes holes all over the place. What is my problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to select all and remove doubles ? (command is accessible via e.g. `W` menu). Also is the **Subdivision Surface** modifier the first one in the stack ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is caused by not connected topology, those faces are separated from the rest of the mesh. Let me illustrate:

This is how a basic plane looks with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image: PlaneSubDiv]

Notice that the edges are all rounded. Now if I extrude an edge, it will remain connected, while if I duplicate it then it is disconnected and I will need to remove doubles:

[image: Plane Edit]

Comment: I had two extra random modifiers and when I removed them the problem seems to have sorted itself cheers

Comment: Like an edge split modifier? Which ones?

Comment: I think I added two extra subdiv surface modifiers